# Images with anchor tag not acting like a link

Tags: html, css, image, hyperlink, anchor

I have a simple [portfolio](http://www.walshx.com/portfolio) which has a grid of images which will eventually be work. I want the images to link to another page with more information about each project when clicked.

For some reason the anchor tags are not acting like links, and you cannot click them.

```
.work {
width: 100%;
margin-top: 50px; }
```

Here is a JS Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/tomwalshx/3msa75a6/

Comment: I don't get your point: you need to link to a new page and says you want to use anchor?? If you want to link to a new page you just need to use a tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the images are floated inside the links, rendering the links 0x0 in size. Instead float the links themselves (and add `display: block;`): http://jsfiddle.net/3msa75a6/1/ (I also added `overflow: hidden;` to `.work` as a "clearfix" + removed media queries you may want to add back)

```
.work a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    max-width: 25%;
}

.work img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Edit: The `display: block;` on the images are so that `line-height` etc is ignored (try without and you'll see some spacing)

Comment: Adding `display:block` for the floated links is not necessary, as `float` implies it in this context already. (See http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo)

Comment: Thanks! works fine, although when i stick the media queries back in it seems to go a little bit wrong?? @powerbuoy

Comment: Because the CSS in the media queries were targeting the images. Change it so that it targets the links instead.

Comment: @CBroe I didn't know that. I always add it for clarity, but might just have to stop :)

Comment: @powerbuoy: Nah, don’t worry, it doesn’t hurt either. (Besides, there might be situations where you want to remove the floating via `float:none` in a media query for small screens, and still have the element accept a `width` or `height` – and then it might come in handy, if the element already has `display:block` set.)

Answer (score 0):

Your only issue is in HTML you use non-existing elements, for example

```
<div class="container">
       <img src="http://walshx.com/portfolio/img/logo.png" id="logo">
 </container>
```

That `</container>` should clearly be `</div>`. You do that with `footer` as well.

After I corrected your HTML, I didn't need to touch css for it to work the way you wanted to http://jsfiddle.net/3msa75a6/7/